# React Native Expo Uncaught Error 'this.props=t'

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, expo

I am relatively new to the world of coding (1 year) and have just recently picked up react.js and react native. When completing a react native tutorial, I stopped and then restarted my packager as my "app" had stopped live or hot loading. I had changed nothing in the code at this point from when it was working. Any help in fixing this error would be appreciated.

I have already tried stopping and restarting both my packager from the expo and my emulator (genymotion). I have also looked at the file paths to ensure I a`m running my packager in the same directory.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome to my FIRST React Native</Text>
    </View>
  );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I then received an error message that read:

```
"Uncaught Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props=t').
```

I expect this to produce the same error code mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see is that Component should not be a function call. Try this

```
export default class App extends Component {
}
```

notice the '()' missing from the Component.

Comment: I made that change and now I am receiving another error on top of the original stating that the application main has not been registered.

Comment: Then your error in not related to this code. try to run expo start -c to clear the bundle cache... or provide more information about your project.

Comment: Depending on how your compiler stops (usually your computer freezes), your compiled javascript cache may get corrupted from time to time. the -c option will clear those cache and recompile the whole project from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you are extendind the Component class as a method, technically there is nothing wrong with that but it might cause conflicts, have you tried this instead:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    // Your code 
}
```

Comment: I made that change and now I am receiving another error on top of the original stating that the application main has not been registered.

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported Text and View and StyleSheet...

```
import {Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
```

You can then try it whether it works